# Download large amount of pdf files from csv url list

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, web-scraping

I have a csv file that has 95k url links that are all pdf files.
I'm using selenium to first login to the page and then loop through the file to trigger the download into my file.

Here is my simple code

```py
download_dir=r"C:\Users\Me\Downloads\pdfs"
    
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs',  {
    "download.default_directory": download_dir,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
    }
)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Me\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe",options = chrome_options)                     
driver.get('https://url.com/')

username = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("email@domain.com")
password.send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_name("Login_Button").click()

driver.find_element_by_name("company").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("Continue_Button").click()

with open(r'C:\Users\Me\Documents\csvTest.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    
    for row in csv_reader:
        pdfUrl = row[0]
        driver.get(pdfUrl)
```

Currently it is being executed one by one about 1500 files an hour. I read about multiprocessing but I'm not familiar on how to implement it and I'm not sure it's possible to do it here given the single driver that is being initiated. Is there a way to trigger the downloads by batches of n files? Instead of downloading them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times `selenium` is an overkill when downloading files, although there are times that its the only thing that works.

The best thing for me to use is `requests` with `multiprocessing`. To do this create a function that downloades the files given the url (and the destination file if needed):

```
import requests
import time

def downloader(url):

    filename = url.split('/')[-1]

    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        print('File already exists')
        return

    for _ in range(5):
        try:
            r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
            break
       except:
           time.sleep(5)
    else:
        print ('Could not fetch file')
        return

    if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in r:
                    f.write(chunk)

    return filename
```

Then create the threads and map that function with a list of urls:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
n = 10 #Number of threads

results = ThreadPool(n).imap_unordered(downloader, urls)
for file in results:
    print(file)
```

I believe this process can speed up things by a lot. You can find more info googling "python download files in parallel".

Comment: Thanks for the response! In your function, i'm not quite sure what you for loop does...

Comment: its not very useful actually. it just shows which files have been downloaded. You don't really need it, but if you delete the script will continue to the next step of the code without waiting for the downloads to finish. I case you  need to wait I think you will have to put a `join()` at the end

Comment: oh now I understand. the for loop in the function makes sure that in case of a small internet connection interruption or in case the server responds late you dont get en error but you retry to download the file. This happens up to five times. If all times fail you get a message and continue to the next url. In other words it makes sure the program does not stop for a few files that didn't get downloaded

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna take a look at threading, but you would have to transform the script on multiple functions (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html, https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

About implementing it, i think you could start a thread only for opening the url's in different tabs and other thread to download the info, close the tab and go to the next one.
That way, i think the script could execute faster, you can also disable chrome GUI to add some extra performance using:

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
```

Comment: Currently, when i trigger driver.get(pdfUrl) it automatically downloads it
If I ll try to open multiple tabs and close them when they are loaded
By multiprocessing i meant threading i guess, thanks for the links, ill get right into it